# Como criar uma anotação personalizada no Spring Boot e executá-la automaticamente quando um método for chamado?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reflexão, annotation

Gostaria de criar minhas próprias anotações. Por exemplo; quando um `controller` do spring for chamado e ele tiver minha anotação, seja executado alguma validação.

```
@GetMapping
@MinhaAnotacao(value="log") // Aqui faria um log, com a request
public ResponseEntity<?> get(){
  ...
}
```

Como poderia fazer isso no spring boot? Eu não tenho muita experiência com anotações no Java. Poderia criar a anotação como no java normal com reflection, mas todos os exemplos que achei, era criado a anotação e depois para executá-la era preciso chamar um método na mão na implementação para fazer alguma ação com aquele método. Como é chamado automaticamente as anotações como o @pathVariable, @Component, @Service, @Bean?

Answer (score 0):

Para esse caso de log, você poderia usar o @Aspect.

Basicamente tu vai criar um interceptor customizado que irá logar o que tu precisa na entrada ou na saida do teu @GetMapping.